# Reference a jPanel component from a separate class

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

Getting to good grips with Java programming and made a simple game.

I want to make a GUI for it with contains two different 'screens'
The best way I have found to swap screens is to use CardLayout.

So, I have a container panel which contains both IntroPanel or GamePanel.

By doing

```
contPanel.setLayout(cl);
            contPanel.add(introPanel, "1");
            contPanel.add(gamePanel, "2");
            cl.show(contPanel, "1");
```

I can change the show value from 1 to 2 and it changes the panel that's showing.

That works fine, my question is:
How can I reference a jButton1 that is on the introPanel?
I want to add an event handler on a jButton but from within this class (so I can swap the panels)

Thanks,

Mike

Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    boolean playAgain = true;

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame GUI = new JFrame();

            GUI.setVisible(true);
            GUI.setSize(500, 500);
            GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

            // Different Panels //
            JPanel contPanel = new JPanel();
            JPanel introPanel = new IntroPanel();
            JPanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
                            introPanel.jLabel1.getText();

            // Card layout //
            contPanel.setLayout(cl);
            contPanel.add(introPanel, "1");
            contPanel.add(gamePanel, "2");
            cl.show(contPanel, "1");
            GUI.add(contPanel);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your introPanel extends JPanel. You probably made this with Netbeans GUI tool so jpanel1 is a private instance. 
Add this to your introPanel code first:

```
public JButton getJButton1() {
    return jbutton1;
}
```

and call it from this class like that:

```
JButton jbutton1 = introPanel.getJButton1();
```